# Create enum while running an application

Tags: spring-boot, enums

I have created Enum like this:So I want to add another enum while my application is running eg:"BLOCKED"..Please Help.

```
public enum LoginStatus {

LOGGEDIN("LOGGEDIN", "Loggedin"),

LOGOUT("LOGOUT", "Logout");

private final String value;
private final String description;

LoginStatus(String value, String description) {
    this.value = value;
    this.description = description;
}


public String value() {
    return this.value;
}


public String getReasonPhrase() {
    return this.description;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create enums at runtime. Enums present a fixed constant, you must define them in source code.